# In Microsoft Access how to Count Specific recurring values that appear in a report

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an attendance report created from a query `qryDriver_Trips`.

I want to count the number of present days which are entered as `P` in my report and if there is a way to highlight the absent days which are marked as `A`.

`Attendance` is the field that displays `A` or `P`.

If there are any `A` I would like them highlighted and all the `P` should be counted.

This is my code in an unbound text box:

```
=Count(IIf([Attendance],"P"))
```

Thank you

Comment: `=Count(IIf([Attendance],"P"))` will show same count for all driver? Attendance report of ? What all columns you have in report?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using conditional aggregation, something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF([Attendance] = "A", 1, 0)) AS num_absent,
    SUM(IIF([Attendance] = "P", 1, 0)) AS num_present
FROM yourTable;
```